Keep seeing a transparent outline when hovering on element
I'm mainly using Material UI, but the same outline appears when I rewrite it to standard HTML. So I have this clickable paperclip element inside my inputbox. It currently looks like this:


            <Box
                className="paperClipBox"
                onClick={(event) => setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)}
                sx={{
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent', // Initial background color
                    borderRadius: '50%',
                    padding: '8px', // Adjust padding for size
                    display: 'inline-flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    outline: 'none',
                    transition: 'background-color 0.3s ease', // Smooth transition for background color
                    '&:hover': {
                        backgroundColor: 'white', // Change to white on hover
                        outline: 'none',
                    },
                    '&:active': {
                        backgroundColor: 'white', // Keep white when clicked
                        outline: 'none',
                    },
                }}
            >
                <PaperIcon />
            </Box>




https://streamable.com/bcs5zj
As you can see you see a transparent outline around the element on hover. I tried setting the outline to none, border-width to 0 etc but I can't seem to get rid of it. I'm using Edge so I thought maybe it is related to the browser but it also shows in Chrome. Instead of using MUI components I rewrote it to standard HTML with div and button but it still shows this outline on hover. See the streamable video link. The confusing part is that the cursor shows that it is clickable in the outline but this does not open the button menu.
If anyone experienced this before and knows a fix it would be greatly appreciated!

I have no environment available to execute your above example. Can you show the plain HTML version you are talking about?
